# Why is `to.` a valid domain name?

Tags: networking, dns

In visiting [`http://to./`](http://to./) you are given a legitimate website.

Is `to.` a valid domain name then, despite not ending with a TLD and having a superfluous period? Why?

Being valid, what would its DNS hierarchy be?

Comment: It's not really a programming related question, but it is quite intriguing; so while I want to mark it 'off-topic' I'm actually quite curious as to the answer ...

Comment: @Unsliced It was originally; @SLaks removed the tag and I assume he is a "higher authority" in this case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The final dot is part of the fully qualified domain name. More information in [this article](http://www.dns-sd.org/TrailingDotsInDomainNames.html). Specifically:

> It's a little-known fact, but fully-qualified (unambiguous) DNS domain names have a dot at the end. People running DNS servers usually know this (if you miss the trailing dots out, your DNS configuration is unlikely to work) but the general public usually doesn't. A domain name that doesn't have a dot at the end is not fully-qualified and is potentially ambiguous.

Answer (score 16):

`to` is the TLD of Tonga.

There is no spec that says that a domain name must have something other than a TLD; Tonga is the only TLD that has an A record for the TLD itself.

However, most browsers will not recognize a domain name that doesn't contain a period, so they use the full FQDN, with a trailing `.`.

Comment: Not a satisfying explanation for the dot *after* the to - which is not superfluous, http://to/ does not work.

Comment: Yes, we need more explanation. I'm getting a "TO./ URL Shortener" service site.

Comment: The `.` at the end forces the browser to realize that it's a domain name.

Comment: http:// to / works for me, as does http:/ /www.google.co m./ (shame SO's formatting breaks the link :P)

Comment: @Henning As I'm using a web proxy config script, my browser attempts to open `to.lancs.ac.uk` when I request `to`.

Comment: a trailing . denotes the root of the hierarchy - it's not mandatory though. Without it, typical dns resolvers will prepend the local domain name if the name has only 1 component, and try a lookup of e.g. http://to.mycompany.com/ first.

Comment: @Henning – I tried it just now with Chrome and it doesn't work for me, tho that could presumably be due to the site served by that name being down.

Answer (score 2):

The [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) represents a hierarchy of domain names. As T. pointed out, if you see a dot at the end of a [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name), it just represents the upper root point of the whole domain name tree.

In the context of web browsers, they tend to be graceful and hide this detail from end users.

Comment: Yet, my browser will display `http://www.youtube.com./yt/about/`, but ***not*** `http://stackoverflow.com./`. So, it appears the treatment by a browser of a URL that has a domain with a period at the end is mixed.

Comment: without trying explicitly, reading any browser's source code, using google: yes, that's what i suspect. they even tend to play with w3c standards, so...