# System.Uri Host contains trailing

Tags: c#, uri

After parsing http traffic I noticed that the Domains I retrieved are incorrect.

Uri www.youtube.com./somepath/index.html

- Expected www.youtube.com
- Actual www.youtube.com.

I've used the following code:

```
var ub = new UriBuilder("www.youtube.com.");
var u = ub.Uri;
Console.WriteLine(u.Host);
```

Is there an easy way to fix this? I don't think the . should be in the Host.

Comment: Are the domain values consistently 'broken' in the same way? For example, always with an extraneous trailing period as shown in your example? Or are you finding other irregularities as well?

Comment: We're trying to group web site visits based on referrer and this seems like a strange quirk in the way Uri and UriBuilder work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for removing beginning as well as trailing (.) dots:

```
string url = "www.youtube.com.";
url = url.trim(".");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not have the problem that you think that you do!

Referring to the question [Why is `to.` a valid domain name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2684137/1497596), [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2684194/1497596) begins with:

> The final dot is part of the fully qualified domain name.

Whether the browser actually resolves a domain name with a trailing period seems to depend on the domain name. For instance, this URL ***is*** displayed by both Firefox 26 and Internet Explorer 9:

```
http://www.youtube.com./yt/about/
                      ^
```

But this URL does ***not*** display:

```
http://stackoverflow.com./about
                        ^
```

To confirm the legitimacy of these two domain names, I passed them both to `nslookup`:

```
nslookup www.youtube.com.
nslookup stackoverflow.com.
```

And indeed, I found that each of the domain names resolved.

So, it seems that using your browser does not appear to be the authoritative method for validating a domain name by itself.

As to why certain URLs resolve in a browser with a period at the end of the domain name while others do not, that appears to be the basis for another question.